# Disable DownloadHub / key list for setPreferences

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

how can I disable that Download window when starting a download via code?
I figured out that I have to set "download.prompt_for_download" to false when I wanna disable the download prompt.
I already tried:

```
bot.SetPreference "profile.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False
bot.SetPreference "profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0
bot.SetPreference "profile.browser.download.panel.shown", False
bot.SetPreference "disable-popup-blocking", True
```

But without any access. Who knows the correct key?

Where can I find a list of all keys?

Warm regards

Answer (score 0):

Selenium only works for browser web page automation. The pop-up is not a part of the web page so Selenium will not be able to recognize it.

And I think any setting in Selenium including `download.prompt_for_download` won't have effect. The pop-up is controlled by the browser setting, and the browser setting is controlled by your `group policy`, you can't override it with Selenium settings.

Comment: In principle a good idea. When I set this option manually in my browser then they are accepted.
I could also set the values by click-event by visiting "edge://settings/downloads" but I can't get the values. So I can't see if I need to click them or not.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can try to modify these settings using Group Policy. So that they can be applied during automation.